# Why is [ordered] typecast not working in a class Powershell 5.0?

Tags: powershell

When trying to use the `[ordered]` typecast in a class in Powershell 5.0 I get the message:

```
Unable to find type [ordered].
```

It works in 5.1. So is there a way to make it work in 5.0?

The class I am trying to use is:

```
class ActivityLog : Windows.Window {
...
    $ticket_Types = [ordered]@{ inc  = 'Incident'
                                req  = 'Request'
                                imac = 'Imac' }
...
}
```

I have a Windows 8.1 and a Windows 7 system where it does not work.

```
PS C:\Users\me> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.0.10586.117
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.10586.117
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

PS C:\Users\me> $PSVersionTable.PSCompatibleVersions

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
1      0      -1     -1
2      0      -1     -1
3      0      -1     -1
4      0      -1     -1
5      0      10586  117
```

Comment: What are you typecasting?

Comment: And what does `$psversiontable` give you? Just to rule out that you're not starting in PowerShell 2 compatibility mode or suchlike...

Comment: Inside PowerShell class? https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869/suggestions/12872805

Comment: @Bill_Stewart e.g. `[ordered]@{bla = 1}`

Comment: @PetSerAl Yes! It didn't come to my mind to try it outside. And indeed when I do dirrectly in the shell it just works! I will update the question.

Comment: @PetSerAl It works. I don't really get it but it works.